# Clarification on multiple join syntax SQL/NoSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, relationship, nosql

I am studying NoSQL databases, and came across a situation which shows the complexity of storing connected data in relational databases. Here's the table structure:

[image]

The two queries are:

Who are Bob's friends:

```
SELECT p1.Person
FROM Person p1 JOIN PersonFriend
ON PersonFriend.FriendID = p1.ID
JOIN Person p2
ON PersonFriend.PersonID = p2.ID
WHERE p2.PERSON = 'Bob'
```

Who is friends with Bob:

```
SELECT p1.Person
FROM Person p1 JOIN PersonFriend
ON PersonFriend.PersonID = p1.ID
JOIN Person p2
ON PersonFriend.FriendID = p2.ID
WHERE p2.PERSON = 'Bob'
```

I think I understand joins pretty well, but I am having some trouble with understanding the connection between the two ON clauses for the given requirement. This is the same for both the queries.

For instance - considering the first query: to get friends of Bob, I need to do this:

1. get `FriendID` from `PersonFriend` where `personID` is 2. This extracts people who are Bob's friends (The clause `where personID is 2` is done by `where p2.person = Bob`).
2. Get `Person` (name) from `Person` where `ID`of the person equals the `FriendID` returned in step 1.

In the first query, the first (inner) join returns a derived table for matching rows based on Person(p1)'s ID column and PersonFriend's FriendID column. But then I'm lost on the second JOIN of the query.

I was even more confused by the second query, where the syntax of join `ON PersonFriend` is the inverse of the first query. I mean, I can understand that the query "Who is friends with Bob" is the inverse of "Who are Bob's friends", but I just cannot visualize the relationship in terms of SQL query.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: But PersonFriend stores all friendships twice... Why?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? Are you referring to the first two rows in PersonFriend, which has 1 and 2 and then 2 and 1? That's because the first row means 2 is 1's friend and second row means 1 is 2's friend. Or so I think.

Comment: Exactly. And can p1 be friends with p2, but p2 not with p1?

Comment: Yeah, for instance: 99(Zach) is 2(Bob's) friend, but 2 is not 99's friend. I'm just having a hard time translating this to the JOIN conditions!

Comment: but that's exactly how the queries are written... what's the problem then

Answer (score 0):

`PersonFriend` table just should tell me: This`PersonID` has this`FriendID` friend. Otherwise is something wrong. If this conditions are right, then your queries are good...

You are just basically saying:

1st query:

Get me those rows, from table `Person p1` where in the table `PersonFriend` is column `FriendID` equals to `p1.ID` (all match), while in the table `PersonFriend` is column `PersonID` equals to `Person p2` `PERSON` only `= 'Bob`'

So you get only those rows from `PersonFriend`, where is a `'Bob'` as `PersonID`

when you make `'Bob'` as `FriendID`, not a `PersonID` you obviously get all persons, that have a match with `'Bob'` as a `FriendID`

I hope you understand now :)